# PostGIS invalid GML representation

Tags: postgis

What is wrong with my geomtery? geometry is [here](http://uloz.to/xRHJu4Qp/geometry-xml).

When I run this command:

```
SELECT st_geomfromgml('content of file geometry.xml');
```

this error was thrown:

```
ERROR:  invalid GML representation
```

I'm using postgres 9.4.1 and PostGIS 2.1.6

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for ST_GeomFromGML](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGML.html) says that the function does "not support SQL/MM curves geometries". It's unfortunate that the error message does not articulate this shortcoming, as the GML has a valid representation to modern software. There [is an enhancement ticket to enable this support](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1986), but there has not been any movement on this after several years.

As a workaround, you can use GDAL/OGR from (e.g.) Python to read the GML and export the WKB to PostGIS:

```
from osgeo import ogr

with open('geometry.xml', 'r') as fp:
    g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromGML(fp.read())
g.GetArea()  # 4519550457.106098

# There is more than one way to insert this to PostGIS, here is one way
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgis host=localhost user=postgres port=5432')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('CREATE TABLE surf(geom geometry);')
curs.execute('INSERT INTO surf(geom) VALUES (%s)', (g.ExportToWkb().encode('hex'),))
conn.commit()

curs.execute('SELECT ST_Area(geom) FROM surf')
curs.fetchone()[0]  # 4519550457.07643
```

The two area calculations (using different methods) are essentially the same, which is reassuring.